# how to redirect to current directory with rewriterule

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect to current directory with rewriterule. 
example: http://www.mySite/directory/subdirectory/index.php

now program is trying to goto 
vvv.mySite/index.php

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
##RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the [`RewriteBase` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) so that the physical path is used.